# Multiple @ServiceActivator methods with the same inputChannel and different signature

Tags: spring-integration

I'm trying to implement an annotation driven event bus (e.g. [Guava Event Bus](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/EventBusExplained)) using spring integration.
I have a *PublishSubscribeChannel* where I publish my events and the idea is to use methods annotated with *@ServiceActivator* as event handlers.
Each method can have a different signature based on the event (payload) they need to handle.

What I noticed is that when an event is published, **all** instances of *ServiceActivatingHandler* created by the *ServiceActivatorAnnotationPostProcessor* are called and an exception for each method that has a signature that does not match the payload. E.g.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 8): Method call: Method handle(model.api.ServiceAvailableEvent) cannot be found on service.eai.TestServiceActivatorImpl2 type
```

Is there a way to define a *@ServiceActivator* method only for specific payload types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct, all the subscribers for the `PublishSubscribeChannel` accept the same message. And if there is no any chance to convert incoming payload into expected method argument type, we get that exception.

If you would like to **filter** unexpected types, you definitely have to use `@Filter` before your `@ServiceActivator`. In other words you do the same as now, but make your flow(s) a bit complex with front filters as subscribers to that `PublishSubscribeChannel`.

You even can rely on the existing `PayloadTypeSelector`:

```
@Bean
@Filter(inputChannel = "publishSubscribeChannel", outputChannel="service1")
public MessageSelector payloadTypeSelector() {
   return new PayloadTypeSelector(...);
}
```

Or, yes, just simple POJO method which checks the `payload` type and marked with the same `@Filter`.

I guess your next question will be like: why doesn't `@ServiceActivator` ignore those types which aren't unsuitable for the target method?

Just don't mix concerns. Service Activator is for `Message` handling in the target business logic. For filtering and skipping we have a difefrent EI pattern - `filter`.

Comment: Ok thank you, I misunderstood the pattern. I would imagine that the same rational applies to gateways. That is, all methods annotated with "@Gateway" ans subscribed to the same requestChannel must take the same payload. Am I correct?

Comment: Note that, if there are multiple methods on the same class with different signatures, the framework will invoke the method that matches the payload - as long as they are unique and unambiguous. No; multiple gateway methods with different signatures can publish to the same channel.

Comment: The `@Gateway` is a fully different story. And it isn't about *subscribe*, but *publish*. `requestChannel` is for sending message via gateway's method invocation. That can be the same channel for different `@Gateway`s, but you should count that exactly their argument becomes as `payload` for message to publish.